# Error re.findall() when used in a iteration over a list from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I converted a column to list from a pandas df:

```
    subsectors = df['subsectors'].tolist()
```

I wanted to separate this kind of strings:
'BuyMeADrink' into 'Buy Me A Drink'

So I used one of the following:

```
    [' '.join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)) for s in subsectors]
```

or

```
    li = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])')
    strings = [li.sub(' ', subsectors) for string in subsectors]
```

or

```
    output=[]
    for i in subsectors:
        output.append(" ".join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', i)))
```

All of the above returned this:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I understand that findall() needs strings not list, but here I am iterating over a list that returns strings, why I get this error then?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show the output of "print(subsectors)" and "print(type(subsectors))" ?

Comment: @Rivers <class 'list'>  subsectors = ['AntibodiesImmunotherapy', 'ProteinsImmunotherapy', 'Wound care', 'Cell therapyImmunotherapy']  it's longer than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subsectors':['BuyMeADrink' ]})

df['subsectors'].str.replace('([A-Z][a-z]*)',r' \1').str.strip()
```

Output:

```
0    Buy Me A Drink
Name: subsectors, dtype: object
```

However, your problem is inherently ambiguous, e.g. how should you split `'ElectionInTheUSA'`

Comment: I see, thanks. Why findall() is not working in this case?

Comment: `' '.join(re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'BuyMeADrink'))` works for me, as does the pandas' equivalence: `df['subsectors'].str.findall('([A-Z][a-z]*)').agg(' '.join)`.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work for me what I wrote in the questions. Maybe it has something to do with strings in my list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, giving you the error message "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" exists only with your second way of doing it.
That's because you pass "subsectors" instead of "string" to "li.sub".

So it should be :

```
li = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])')
strings = [li.sub(' ', string) for string in subsectors]
```

Complete code :

```
import re

subsectors = ['AntibodiesImmunotherapy', 'ProteinsImmunotherapy', 'Wound care', 'Cell therapyImmunotherapy']

strings = [' '.join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)) for s in subsectors]
print(strings)

li = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])')
strings = [li.sub(' ', string) for string in subsectors]
print(strings)

strings=[]
for i in subsectors:
    strings.append(" ".join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', i)))
print(strings)
```

Comment: strings = [' '.join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)) for s in subsectors]
print(strings)  returns me the same error

Comment: Have you tried the (complete) code above ? It's working with the list you provided in comments. Perhaps the error is with the list called "subsectors" then.

Comment: yes, it doesn't work. Yes, there is something in the list, but I don't understand what. With the code of Quang it works so probably there are some strings in the list that cause interference.